# Fade In Fade Out Animations

Tags: wpf, xaml

Currently I try to achieve an Fade In Animation when my Button is set to visible and on the opposite an Fade Out Animation when my Button is set to collapsed. I want to do this in pure XAML. The following Code is my attempt:

```xaml
<Style x:Key="NavigateBackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBackground" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard >
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             From="0.0" To="1.0" 
                                                             Duration="0:0:0.7"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard >
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             From="1.0" To="0.0" 
                                                             Duration="0:0:0.7"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>                                
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

What is going wrong:

When I set the Button visible the Fade In Animation triggers like I expected. But immediately after the Animation the Collapsed Animation triggers and the Button is Fading out. I already triple checked my .cs Code. I don't set the visibility instant back to collapsed when I set the Button Visibility to visible.

So what's wrong with my XAML? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first Trigger (Fade opacity from 0 to 1) is fired when Visibility is set to `Visible`. However your second Trigger fires at the same time, because you declared the storyboard in the `ExitActions`.

```
Collapsed --> Visible
(Exit)        (Enter)
```

If you remove these two lines

```
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
```

it would probably be what you intended to do. There is however still one problem: The fade-out won't be visible because it doesn't matter how opaque a `Collapsed` element is, it will be invisible instantly.

What you could do is use another property (e.g. `IsEnabled`) or a custom attached property instead:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <!-- Fade to 1 -->
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <!-- Fade to 0 -->
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

Probably not what you had in mind, but unfortunately there is no way to circumvent `Visibility` settings.

---

If you don't want to waste your `IsEnabled` for the Animation, you could create your own attached property and use that to control the animation:

```cs
public static class AnimationProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFadedOutProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsFadedOut", typeof(bool), typeof(AnimationProperties), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    public static void SetIsFadedOut(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsFadedOutProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsFadedOut(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(IsFadedOutProperty);
    }
}
```

```xaml
<Trigger Property="yourLocalNamespace:AnimationProperties.IsFadedOut" Value="False">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <!-- Fade to 1 -->
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <!-- Fade to 0 -->
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

```cs
bool currentValue = AnimationProperties.GetIsFadedOut(btn);
AnimationProperties.SetIsFadedOut(btn, !currentValue);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I planned to do. I didn't consider your second Statement. Looks like I Need to find a way to delay the Visibilitychange to collapsed.

Comment: Depending on how you use this, an attached property might be a good alternative to wasting `IsEnabled` (code soon).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try this out and Play with it!